# Large amounts of json data, slow browser evaluation of json data

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, handlebars.js

Question, when sending a lot of JSON to the browser, is it smarter to break it down into small chunks, say doing something like, for(;;){JSON-data} then you split on your string for 'for(;;)' and then evaluate the JSON strings by themselves, process, then rinse/repeat since it can cause the browser to hang when you send massive amounts of JSON to then be immediately evaluated?..

Example:

```
    {huge-JSON(1-2MB)}

// vs

    for(;;);{JSON-data}
    for(;;);{JSON-data}
    for(;;);{JSON-data}
    for(;;);{JSON-data}
    for(;;);{JSON-data}
    for(;;);{JSON-data}
```

then parse the script, remove the for(;;); strings, then split on "\n" and loop through the array and evaluate each JSON-data set one-by-one.

I was just thinking this may be quicker than trying to evaluate one massive JSON data set all at once, especially if you need quick html output.

Comment: Why would you use `for(;;);` as a delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I dont really understand your idea of using for(;;) to break down a huge json. Also, adding something, parsing, removing and splitting the data before using it would just be an extra overhead on the browser.

Also, if you are preparing a html string inside a for loop before rendering it, just make sure you dont render it all at once after the loop ends. But keep on rendering it inside the loop so that you dont keep the user waiting till the loop finishes the execution. This should help you deliver a quick html output when there is a huge json for the browser to work on.

Hope this might help you.

Comment: Actually, rendering piece by piece is slower.  The browser has to re-evaluate styles every time you change the DOM.  Appending it all in memory and then adding to the page at the end would provide better performance